# Change heatmap's yticks for multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is the seaborn heatmap generated from a MultiIndex dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

years = range(2016,2019)
months = range(1,6)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years,months]))
df['vals'] = np.random.random(size=len(df))
sns.heatmap(df)
```

[image]

The above heatmap's yticks show both years and months. Is there a way to change the heatmap's yticks to only show the years, like below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the `yticklabels` param of [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to set custom labels

1. Create a list of empty strings except at the desired indexes

   **Either:** Only show labels when the month is 3

   ```
   labels = [year if month == 3 else '' for year, month in df.index]
   ```

   **Or:** Only show labels on specific rows (index 2, 7, and 12 in OP's example)

   ```
   labels = [year if row in (2, 7, 12) else ''
             for row, (year, month) in enumerate(df.index)]
   ```
2. Then set these labels via `yticklabels`

   ```
   sns.heatmap(df, yticklabels=labels)
   ```

Notes:

- These conditions like `month == 3` and `row in (2, 7, 12)` are specific to OP's example and will **need to be adjusted for real data.**
- If you have a `datetime` index (not just strings), see [this answer for spacing out `datetime` yticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70149906/13138364).

---

[image]