# Seaborn heatmap change date frequency of yticks

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

My problem is similar to the one encountered on this topic: [Change heatmap's yticks for multi-index dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897981/change-heatmaps-yticks-for-multi-index-dataframe)

I would like to have yticks every 6 months, with them being the index of my dataframe. But I can't manage to make it work.

The issue is that my dataframe is 13500*290 and the answer given in the link takes a long time and doesn't really work (see image below).

This is an example of my code without the solution from the link, this part works fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(datetime(1984, 6, 10), datetime(2021, 1, 14), freq='1D') )

for i in range(0,290):
    df['Pt{0}'.format(i)] = np.random.random(size=len(df))
    
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='PuOr', vmin = np.min(np.min(df)), vmax = np.max(np.max(df)), cbar_kws={"label": "Ice Velocity (m/yr)"})
```

This part does not work for me and produces the figure below, which shouldn't have the stack of ylabels on the yaxis:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
years = df.index.get_level_values(0)
ytickvalues = [year if index in (2, 7, 12) else '' for index, year in enumerate(years)]
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='PuOr', vmin = np.min(np.min(df)), vmax = np.max(np.max(df)), cbar_kws={"label": "Ice Velocity (m/yr)"}, yticklabels = ytickvalues)
```

[image]

Comment: Due to the size of your DataFrame, I think it will take a long time to render the heatmap regardless of the ytickvalues. Perhaps you could downsample the data to every 6 months when creating the heatmap?

Comment: I don't really want to downsample because I am interested in all the variations displayed, and it would really make the plot difficult to interpret with a 6month downsampling. But the long waiting time is not really a problem, the main issue is that it just doesn't work

Comment: On my system, this works without issue and correctly scales the number of ylabels, and plots in **1.47 s ± 17.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)**. Make certain you're using the current version on seaborn (0.11.2) and matplotlib (3.4.3). See the [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9fwP.jpg)

Comment: If you're using conda, then at the Anaconda prompt `conda update --all`

Comment: 13_000 days without averaging is almost certainly aliased when looking at it on a normal sized monitor.  You should smooth and then down sample if your signs has any high frequency information in it.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I will edit my code. @Trenton McKinney the first part of the code also works for me, what does not work is the 2nd part of the code (under the line "With the solution:". It gives me that figure with the ylabels compressed and stacked on the yaxis it seems. I don't know if it is only on my pc or if the issue would be the same for everybody ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple ways to adapt that link for your use case (1 label per 6 months):

1. **Either:** Show an empty string except on Jan 1 and Jul 1 (i.e., when `%m%d` evals to `0101` or `0701`)

   ```
   labels = [date if date.strftime('%m%d') in ['0101', '0701'] else ''
             for date in df.index.date]
   ```
2. **Or:** Show an empty string except every ~365/2 days (i.e., when `row % 183 == 0`)

   ```
   labels = [date if row % 183 == 0 else ''
             for row, date in enumerate(df.index.date)]
   ```

Note that you don't have a MultiIndex, so you can just use `df.index.date` (no need for `get_level_values`).

---

Here is the output with a minimized version of your `df`:

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='PuOr', cbar_kws={'label': 'Ice Velocity (m/yr)'},
            vmin=df.values.min(), vmax=df.values.max(),
            yticklabels=labels)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like seaborn 0.11.2 and matplotlib 3.4.3 are already spacing the labels to an acceptable density. This answer allows for specifying the precise time distance between the labels though.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yep, for default spacing, i get something similar to your output (though it takes my system _much_ longer than 1.47s)